# set breakpoint while in debugger?

Tags: ess, r, debug

Is it possible to set a breakpoint on an arbitrary line while already established in `browser()`? As a use-case: if I `debug(myfunc)` and while in `Browse[2]> ...` I realize that I need to jump forward to a point in the source file. My two current methods for dealing with this are:

1. Exit the function, set the breakpoint where I want it, and re-enter the browser for the function.
2. Continue line-by-line through the function, where my only way to speed things up a little is to use `f`inish execution of the current loop (or function). (This can be arduous with functions that are hundreds of lines.)

What I'd love to be able to do is:

3. Navigate to the line I want, tag it for debugging (`C-c C-t C-b`, I think), then `c`ontinue (`M-S-c`) in the debugger, where it will then continue unabated until it encounters my just-set breakpoint.

R-3.2.5-64, emacs-24.5.1 (i686-w64-mingw32), ess-16.04 (elpa: 20160602.203)

**Edit**: `browser()` is a debugger intended for in-environment inspection at breakpoints (either intentional or reactive) of uncompiled R code. This is specific to ESS, and more so to `ess-tracebug` within it. (Heck, perhaps the answer is solely R, in which case I can migrate to SO.)